# 'e' is not defined no-undef in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React , {useState} from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Typed from 'react-typed';

const Register = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '', 
    email: '', 
    password: '', 
    error: null, 
    loading: false,
  });
  const {first_name, last_name, email, password, error, loading} = data;
  const handleChange = e => {
    setData({...data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  };
  const handleSubmit = async => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(data)
  }
```

```
Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR
[eslint] 
src\pages\Register.js
  Line 19:5:  'e' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

i don't have any idea why it's happening i am new to react and i am getting the error that e is not defined. can someone please tell me what is it that i am doing wrong

Comment: You've a typo, the `handleSubmit` function doesn't declare `e`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are accessing `e` inside `handleSubmit` function and it does not exists in its scope.
To fix this, pass the event as the parameter for `handleSubmit` function.

```
 const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(data)
  }
```

Comment: Just FYI for future reference, issues caused by typos like these are not considered valuable for future readers. There is a specific "vote to close" (VTC) reason specifically for "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" issues.

Answer (score 0):

your handleSubmit function isn't written correctly -

```
const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(data)
  }
```

Comment: Just FYI for future reference, issues caused by typos like these are not considered valuable for future readers. There is a specific "vote to close" (VTC) reason specifically for "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" issues.